# Stochastic variable and density

Tags: measure-theory

I have some homework that says:

$X$ is a real-valued stochastic variable, uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$ and let $Y=-2 \ln X$. Hence $E(Y)=2$. Find the density of $Y$ and use this to recompute $E(Y).

Is the density simply $-2ln X$ or am I misunderstanding the question?

Thanks

Comment: $E[Y]$ is a number. Perhaps the question is find the density of $Y$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst You are right, I have updated the question

Comment: To find the density, compute $P[-2\ln X \leq y] = P[X \geq e^{-\frac{y}{2}}]$ and differentiate it

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Can you tell me which theorem you are using?

Comment: for every $X$ such that $-2 \ln X \leq y$, we also have $X \geq e^{-y/2}$ and vice versa. To see this, rearrange the inequality in terms of $X$. Hence the probability of this is the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Guide**:

If the CDF of rv $Y$ is differentiable then its derivative serves as PDF of $Y$.

Find the CDF of $Y$.

Take its derivate.

Then verify that $\mathbb EY=\int yf_Y(y)\;dy=2$ where $f_Y$ denotes the derivative.